# How do i integrate a form with a table?

Tags: php

Here is my current TABLE:

```
print "<table cellpadding=12px>";

print "<th>Name</ th>";
print "<th>Price</ th>";
print "<th>Image</ th>";


if ($cat == 'Clothes'){

       $query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Type = 'Clothes' ORDER BY ProductPrice";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {
    echo " <tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] .  "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . '&pound'. $row['ProductPrice'] .  "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<img width=200px height=200px src="./ProductsPic/' . $row['ProductPic'] . '" />' . "</td>";

    echo "<td> <a href=cart.php?action=add&id=".$row["ID"].">Add to Cart</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

       }
   print "</table>";
```

However, when i click on the "add to cart" link, it only sends the ID of the product to the cart. I somehow need to send the price and name of that product (possibly hidden data?). So would it be easy to integrate a form into my table, or would there be another way i can add the name and price of the product into my cart array?

Answer (score 0):

If the `ID` field is the unique key that represents the product, then you can simply fetch its other details from the database. Otherwise you can do the following:

You could add more parameters to the query string.

```
echo "<td> <a href=cart.php?action=add&id=".$row["ID"]."&price=".$row['ProductPrice']."&name=".$row['ProductName'].">Add to Cart</a></td>";
```

You could create a form with hidden values, and convert the *Add to Cart* link to a submit button.

```
echo '
<form action="cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="'.$row['ProductPrice'].'">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="'.$row['ProductName'].'">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['ID'].'">
    <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
';
```